# Limit the width of an element(Tailwind)

Tags: css, tailwind-css, jsx, nextui

I have a Card component:

```
<div className="max-w-64">
            <Card className="">
                <CardHeader className="justify-between gap-1">
                    <div className="flex">
                        <Avatar isBordered radius="full" size="md" src="/avatars/avatar-1.png" className="mt-1" />
                        <Spacer x={2}/>
                        <div className="flex flex-col gap-1 items-start justify-center">
                            <div className="flex gap-2">
                                <h4 className="text-small font-semibold leading-none text-default-600">{name}</h4>
                                <h4 className="text-small font-semibold leading-none text-default-400">Id:{id}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex text-default-400">
                                <i className="bi-geo-alt"/>
                                <h4 className="text-small tracking-tight"> {location}</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Button
                        className={isFollowed ? "bg-transparent text-foreground border-default-200" : ""}
                        color="primary"
                        radius="full"
                        size="sm"
                        variant={isFollowed ? "bordered" : "solid"}
                        onPress={() => setIsFollowed(!isFollowed)}
                    >
                        {isFollowed ? "Cancel" : "Register"}
                    </Button>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody className="px-3 py-0 text-small text-default-400">
                    <p>
                        Starts {startDate.getDate() + '.' + (startDate.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + startDate.getFullYear()} at {startDate.getHours()}:{startDate.getMinutes()}
                    </p>
                    <span className="pt-2">
                            Tags:
                        </span>
                    <div className="container">
                        <p>
                            Description:
                        </p>
                        <p className="truncate">
                            {description}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </CardBody>
                <CardFooter className="gap-3">
                    <div className="flex gap-1">
                    <p className="font-semibold text-default-400 text-small">1</p>
                        <p className=" text-default-400 text-small">Registered</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex gap-1">
                        <p className="font-semibold text-default-400 text-small">{space}</p>
                        <p className="text-default-400 text-small">Capacity</p>
                    </div>
                </CardFooter>
            </Card>
        </div>
```

I have set max width with max-w-64, didn't work though:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEdU4.png)

I have tried multiple Tailwind classes, including text-wrap for the description, still nothing.
I suspect there is a certain place I have to add something like width-fixed or overflow-hidden, yet I can't really understand where.

Comment: Hi @m1st, your question doesn't provide a reproducible scenario, so I can't debug accordingly. However, the correct way to debug CSS is by using DevTools. Check the card element and unselect each class attached until it's fixed. Most likely caused by `flex-grow` or a CSS grid configuration on a parent element. Try `flex-grow-0` but also inspect the CSS, this is being caused by a parent element.